# Show that a field of characteristic $0$ is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Show that if a field $F$ has characteristic $0$, then it is of infinite order.

Please someone help me. It is an unsolved exercise in my book, it is not homework.

Comment: If $n\times 1\neq 0$ for every $n$ then these elements are all different

Comment: Well, suppose that F has finitely many elements.  Then the subset {1, 1+1, 1+1+1,...} of F  has only finitely many distinct elements.  What would that imply?

Comment: If it were finite, adding the multiplicative identity $1$ a number of times (say $p$) gets you the additive identity $0$.

Answer (score 5):

A ring $R$ has characteristic zero if there is a monomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to R$. What does this imply about the relationship between $|\mathbb{Z}|$ and $|R|$?

Comment: Surely you meant to write $|R|$ at the end of your answer.

Comment: Indeed. But $\mathbb{R}$ also has characteristic zero...

Comment: Beautiful solution. I can go to bed happy.

Answer (score 2):

A field with characteristic zero contains a subfield isomorphic to Q. The results follows by Q